# Extract NetCDF variable that have more than 4 dimension using brick function in raster package

Tags: r, netcdf

I want to extract a variable called NVEL from the netCDF file which has five dimensions (i, j, tile, k, time)
where i is longitude, j is latitude, k is the level of depths
I want to extract NVEL(i, j, tile=3, k=1st level, time)
the input file can be downloaded from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/12NQp_uLr_IZLLU6Fzr555gKGGJlrRE4H/view?usp=sharing

```
NVEL<- brick("NVEL_1992_01.nc", varname= "NVEL", lvar=1, nl=1)
NVEL <- NVEL[[which(getZ(NVEL) == 3)]]
```

This does not work.
How to deal with a variable of 5 dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that this returns 50 (k) * 13 (tiles) * 1 (time) = 650 layers

```
library(terra)
f <- "NVEL_1992_01.nc"
x <- rast(f)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 90, 650  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : -0.5, 89.5, -0.5, 89.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#data source : NVEL_1992_01.nc 
#names       : NVE_1, NVE_2, NVE_3, NVE_4, NVE_5, NVE_6, ...
```

The order is k-wise (and tile-wise within tiles). See (the rather lengthy) output from

```
terra::describe(f)
```

You can extract that information like this:

```
d <- describe(f, print=FALSE)
d <- unlist(strsplit(d, "\n"))
i <- grep("NETCDF_DIM_k=", d)
j <- grep("NETCDF_DIM_tile=", d)
k <- sapply(strsplit(d[i], "="), function(x) x[2])
tile <- sapply(strsplit(d[j], "="), function(x) x[2])
kt <- paste0("k", k, "_tile", tile)
names(x) <- kt
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 90, 650  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : -0.5, 89.5, -0.5, 89.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#data source : NVEL_1992_01.nc 
#names       : k0_tile0, k0_tile1, k0_tile2, k0_tile3, k0_tile4, k0_tile5, ...
```

This should happen automatigically in a future version. You can continue with `terra` (very similar to `raster`) or take the data back to a RasterBrick by doing

```
b <- brick(x*1)
```

(multiplying to get the values out of the file)